# How to read a custom header in owin middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am sending a custom HTTP header *X-TYPE* from JavaScript client to ASP.Net Web API.

I see this header in controller `HttpContext`, but accessing request headers via `IOwinContext` inside middleware doesn't provide custom headers.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to access headers via the request in the context.

For example

```
public class MyCustomMiddleware : OwinMiddleware {

    public MyCustomMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next) {

    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {

        var request = context.Request;
        var headers = request.Headers;
        var headerKey = "X-TYPE";
        // custome header
        if (headers.ContainsKey(headerKey)) {
            var xType = headers[headerKey];
            //...
        }

        // continue pipeline
        await Next.Invoke(context);

        //...
    }
}
```